# Why doesn't grep return TRUE in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm adapting some of my code from Bash to C++ and I have no idea why this allways returns FALSE.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    if ( system ("grep -q zswap.enabled=1 /etc/default/grub") ) {
        std::cout << "   zswap.enabled=1 ?: Yes\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "   zswap.enabled=1 ?: No\n"; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW, with C++11 or C++14 you could use regex ....

Comment: Noted for next time. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You know, that's covered in the documentation for `system()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Bash interprets 0 as "success" while C++ interprets it as "false". It's a historical thing that's annoying, but by no means the most annoying thing you'll encounter when porting lengthy shell scripts to C/C++.

Comment: It's not just historical, nor is it annoying, there are very good reasons 0 is interpreted as success. There's only one way the function will succeed, whereas there are many ways it can fail. Having 0 be success means that when a command fails, you can both know it failed, and know why.

Comment: The two most widespread programming platforms (Bash/C) on the most widespread platform in the universe (Linux) having different opinions about how to express "success" is most certainly annoying. The problem is that either community has weighty reasons to stick to their convention, but this is only fine until they clash.

Comment: @KilianFoth There's no reason in C you can't literally define SUCCESS as 0 and compare the result to SUCCESS.

Comment: Be evil and redefine TRUE and FALSE somewhere deep down in the header structure. Maybe make it not do it on Tuesdays!

Comment: If you include `<stdlib.h>`, you can use `EXIT_SUCCESS` (0) and `EXIT_FAILURE` (1).

Comment: Actually, the notion of zero meaning success is very common in Linux and C: `errno` is zero if the previous operation succeeds.  Similarly, many functions *do* conventionally return zero on success, except those that return a file descriptor or a size (in which case `-1` is reserved for failure).  (This is *not* true for Windows API, however, where there is a tendency to use `1` for success and `0` for failure.)